# Weird after-exit error on coroutine test module on Windows x64

Tags: c, windows, assembly, 64-bit

I built in Windows x86_64 ASM the core of a single coroutine utility and I set up a testbed for testing. My project is setup using `cmake` and the generator `Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64`. However, there's a crash *after* the main has exited.

The repository where all the code is located is: https://github.com/JoaoBaptMG/ReboundTheGame/tree/master/Coroutine
(it might be advisable to clone from it, because I'm afraid even the CMake configuration I set up might be flawed)

The ASM code for Windows x64 is [here](https://github.com/JoaoBaptMG/ReboundTheGame/blob/master/Coroutine/asm-impl/coroutine-win-x64.asm), assembled with MASM. Here's the listing

```
    context_rsp equ 0
    context_rbp equ context_rsp + 8
    context_rdi equ context_rbp + 8
    context_rsi equ context_rdi + 8
    context_r12 equ context_rsi + 8
    context_r13 equ context_r12 + 8
    context_r14 equ context_r13 + 8
    context_r15 equ context_r14 + 8
    context_xmm6 equ context_r15 + 8
    context_xmm7 equ context_xmm6 + 16
    context_xmm8 equ context_xmm7 + 16
    context_xmm9 equ context_xmm8 + 16
    context_xmm10 equ context_xmm9 + 16
    context_xmm11 equ context_xmm10 + 16
    context_xmm12 equ context_xmm11 + 16
    context_xmm13 equ context_xmm12 + 16
    context_xmm14 equ context_xmm13 + 16
    context_xmm15 equ context_xmm14 + 16
    context_rbx equ context_xmm15 + 16
    context_num_saved_variables equ context_rbx + 8

.code
    extern malloc : PROC
    extern free : PROC

;=======================================================================================
;
; coroutine_t coroutine_new(coroutine_entry_point point, size_t stack_size)
; - rcx: point
; - rdx: stack_size
; - rax: new coroutine_t*
;
;=======================================================================================

    public coroutine_new
coroutine_new:
    ; allocate memory for the context data plus the stack
    mov [rsp+8], rcx
    mov [rsp+16], rdx
    sub rsp, 32
    lea rcx, [rdx + context_num_saved_variables]  ; allocate everything in a single chunk
    call malloc

    ; If allocation fails, return early
    test rax, rax
    jz early_return

    ; Initialize the stack for a stub entry point
    mov rcx, [rsp+40]
    mov rdx, [rsp+48]
    lea rdx, [rax + rdx + context_num_saved_variables-24]

    mov [rdx+16], rcx                      ; Bottom of stack: return pointer
    mov [rdx+8], rax                       ; Middle of stack: context_t parameter
    lea rcx, entry_point                   ; 
    mov [rdx], rcx                         ; Top of stack: entry_point stub

    mov [rax + context_rsp], rdx           ; Move the stack pointer to its place

early_return:
    add rsp, 32
    ret

;=======================================================================================
; This implements the stub entry point for proper funcion entering
;=======================================================================================
entry_point:
    ; assemble the function's parameters
    mov rcx, [rsp]
    mov rdx, rax
    sub rsp, 32
    call qword ptr [rsp+40]
    add rsp, 32

    ; retrieve the parameters again
    mov rcx, [rsp]

    ; invalidate the own method's stack - this is safe
    mov rsp, 0

    ; yield a last time
    jmp cryield

;=======================================================================================
;
; void* coroutine_resume(coroutine_t coro, void* param);
; void* coroutine_yield(coroutine_t coro, void* param);
; - rdi: coro
; - rsi: param
; - rax: param returned from the entry point
;
;=======================================================================================
    public coroutine_resume
coroutine_resume:
    public coroutine_yield
coroutine_yield:
    mov [rsp+8], rcx
    mov [rsp+16], rcx

    test rcx, rcx ; Careful with nullptr's
    jz return_nullptr

    ; If the coroutine is ended, return
    cmp qword ptr [rcx + context_rsp], 0
    jz return_nullptr

    ; Set the return value as the param passed
    mov rax, rdx

cryield:
    ; Exchange callee-saved registers
    xchg [rcx + context_rsp], rsp
    xchg [rcx + context_rbp], rbp
    xchg [rcx + context_rdi], rdi
    xchg [rcx + context_rsi], rsi
    xchg [rcx + context_r12], r12
    xchg [rcx + context_r13], r13
    xchg [rcx + context_r14], r14
    xchg [rcx + context_r15], r15
    xchg [rcx + context_rbx], rbx

    ; Exchange XMM registers (helper macro)
exchange_xmm macro xmmn : REQ, context_xmmn : REQ
    movdqa xmm0, xmmn
    movdqa xmmn, [rcx + context_xmmn]
    movdqa [rcx + context_xmmn], xmm0
endm

    ; Exchange XMM registers
    exchange_xmm xmm6, context_xmm6
    exchange_xmm xmm7, context_xmm7
    exchange_xmm xmm8, context_xmm8
    exchange_xmm xmm9, context_xmm9
    exchange_xmm xmm10, context_xmm10
    exchange_xmm xmm11, context_xmm11
    exchange_xmm xmm12, context_xmm12
    exchange_xmm xmm13, context_xmm13
    exchange_xmm xmm14, context_xmm14
    exchange_xmm xmm15, context_xmm15
    ret

return_nullptr:
    mov rax, 0
    ret

;=======================================================================================
;
; int is_coroutine_ended(coroutine_t coro)
; - rdi: coro
; - rax: 1 if coroutine is ended, 0 if it is not
;
;=======================================================================================
    public is_coroutine_ended
is_coroutine_ended:
    test rcx, rcx
    jz coroutine_is_ended

    cmp qword ptr [rcx + context_rsp], 0
    jz coroutine_is_ended
    mov rax, 0
    ret

coroutine_is_ended:
    mov rax, 1
    ret

;=======================================================================================
;
; void coroutine_destroy(coroutine_t coro)
; - rdi: coro
;
;=======================================================================================
    public coroutine_destroy
coroutine_destroy:
    sub rsp, 32
    test rcx, rcx
    jz dont_delete_unended_coroutine

    cmp qword ptr [rcx + context_rsp], 0
    jnz dont_delete_unended_coroutine
    call free
dont_delete_unended_coroutine:
    add rsp, 32
    ret

END
```

The header file for the included functions is [here](https://github.com/JoaoBaptMG/ReboundTheGame/blob/master/Coroutine/asm-impl/coroutine.h), listed:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef volatile void* coroutine_t;
typedef const void* (*coroutine_entry_point)(coroutine_t, const void*);

#if _WIN32 && _M_IX86
#define CDECL __cdecl
#else
#define CDECL
#endif

coroutine_t CDECL coroutine_new(coroutine_entry_point point, size_t stack_size);
const void* CDECL coroutine_resume(coroutine_t coro, const void* param);
const void* CDECL coroutine_yield(coroutine_t coro, const void* param);
int CDECL is_coroutine_ended(coroutine_t coro);
void CDECL coroutine_destroy(coroutine_t coro);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The `main` routine that calls the coroutine operations is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "asm-impl/coroutine.h"

const void* entry_point(coroutine_t parent, const void* value)
{
    int n = 0;
    printf("coroutine receives %s from main (n = %d)\n", value, n);
    n++;
    value = coroutine_yield(parent, "cr1");   
    printf("coroutine receives %s from main (n = %d)\n", value, n);
    n++;
    value = coroutine_yield(parent, "cr2");
    printf("coroutine receives %s from main (n = %d)\n", value, n);
    n++;
    value = coroutine_yield(parent, "cr3");
    printf("coroutine receives %s from main (n = %d)\n", value, n);
    return "cr4";
}

int main()
{
    // Small text
    coroutine_t coro = coroutine_new(entry_point, 4096);

    const void* value;
    int m = 7;
    value = coroutine_resume(coro, "mn1");
    printf("main receives %s from coroutine (m = %d)\n", value, m);
    m--;
    value = coroutine_resume(coro, "mn2");
    printf("main receives %s from coroutine (m = %d)\n", value, m);
    m--;
    value = coroutine_resume(coro, "mn3");
    printf("main receives %s from coroutine (m = %d)\n", value, m);
    m--;
    value = coroutine_resume(coro, "mn4");
    printf("main receives %s from coroutine (m = %d)\n", value, m);

    coroutine_destroy(coro);
    return 0;
}
```

The code prints correctly the operations interleved between both `main` and `entry_point`, giving this output:

```
coroutine receives mn1 from main (n = 0)
main receives cr1 from coroutine (m = 7)
coroutine receives mn2 from main (n = 1)
main receives cr2 from coroutine (m = 6)
coroutine receives mn3 from main (n = 2)
main receives cr3 from coroutine (m = 5)
coroutine receives mn4 from main (n = 3)
main receives cr4 from coroutine (m = 4)
```

However, *after* returning from main, the program throws an exception (not a C++ exception, but seems to be a Windows-specific C exception). The error is the following:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDFABB445D (ntdll.dll) in Coroutine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00007FFDF7230961.

It fails on line `if (!has_cctor)` (line 268 on file `crt\src\vcruntime\exe_common.inl`) around this code:

```
    int const main_result = invoke_main();

    // ...

    if (!__scrt_is_managed_app())
        exit(main_result);

    if (!has_cctor)
        _cexit();

    // Finally, we terminate the CRT:
    __scrt_uninitialize_crt(true, false);
    return main_result;
```

This is a weird bug that I can't realize why it happens. It seems nothing related to my ASM, yet if I remove all the coroutine code it ends gracefully. What could it be?

Comment: You are not following the Windows 64-bit calling conventions. Your assembly functions have no unwind codes, you are not keeping the stack on a 16-byte boundary, and you are swapping stacks without updating the stack bookkeeping. Just use fibers instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I thought the 16-byte boundary requirement was only for System V ABI, I didn’t find it on Windows documentation. And what “exactly” is this stack bookkeeping (that I also didn’t find)?

Comment: *"It seems nothing related to my ASM"* that's absolutely normal, many bugs in assembly either don't demonstrate at all, or they make malfunction completely unrelated part of application (source wise unrelated I mean. Of course the bug behaviour *does* relate to the original bug, but it may be as subtle as overwriting memory of code part which will touch that memory several minutes later, and crash due to it). Just make sure your assembly is perfect 100% correct, and you are good. ... not easy.

Comment: In [x64 Software Conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions), [Overview of x64 Calling Conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/overview-of-x64-calling-conventions) says, "The stack pointer must be aligned to 16 bytes in any region of code that isn’t part of an epilog or prolog, except within leaf functions." It doesn't talk about specifically changing stacks because that's not specific to 64-bit Windows. The rules about changing stacks on 64-bit Windows are the same as on 32-bit Windows (basically, don't do it directly; use fibers).

Comment: So I really have to call to the OS just to change a bunch of registers? It was so “trivial” on Unix (just save the correct registers, align the stack and move one)... anyway, I’ll try to make some changes here.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Or an idea why?

I am running into what seems to be this exact issue under some conditions. Unfortunately only in a heavily optimized version of my build, so I'm having a hard time debugging it.

Edit: I should say that I'm using the experimental coroutine feature of C++17 with Visual Studio 2017